# Adjusting the height of a div that has property "display: table-cell"

Tags: css, parent-child, html

I am trying to vertically center a div inside another div, regardless of the size of both div's

I am doing this:

```
<div id='outer_div'>
    <div id='inner_div'></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#outer_div {
   display: table-row; 
   height: 200px; 
   width: 200px
}

#inner_div {
   display: table-cell; 
   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 500px; 
   width: 500px
}
```

I put larger dimensions for the inner div on purpose. What happens is that even if I put a width of `1000px`, the width of `inner_div` is ceiled at `200px` because of the `outer_div`'s width (and this is what I want).

But for the height, it is not ceiled and I would like it to be ceiled to the height of the outer div.

What I want is `inner_div` to remain at the same size as `outer_div`, no matter what height I give to `outer_div` in CSS. **I basically want it to be the same size as its parent**.

---

**EDIT**:

I only put text inside those div's. So let's say I have an outer div of `200px*200px` (it has `display: table-row`), and the inner div is defined by CSS as `500px*500px` and it has dummy text inside. My expected result is to have the inner div shrunk down to `200px*200px`. It is successfully "shrunk" by the outer div for the width, but NOT for the height. What I want is to have it shrunk on the height as well (so the inner div adjusts automatically in case I change the height of the outer div)

How do I go about that?

Comment: What should happen? Internal scrollbar? Hidden overflow? Scaled down?

Comment: I want the innerdiv to remain at 200px by 200px, no matter what height I give to it in CSS. I basically want it to be the same size as it's parent. Thanks

Comment: I can't speak for anybody else, but your question is making no sense to me. If you want the inner div to be the same size as it's parent, what's the point of trying to center it?

Comment: Hi, because what I want ultimately, is that everything inside the inner div be vertically centered. So I need an inner div with "display: table-cell" inside a div with "display: table-row"

Comment: Give me desired effect: inner div has a 50x50 image in it; 400x400 image; 140x700; 700x140. What sizes are you expecting

Comment: I only put text inside those div's. So let's say I have an outer div of 200px*200px (it has `display: table-row`), and the inner div is defined by css as 500px*500px and it has dummy text inside. My expected result is to have the inner div as a 200px*200px. It is successfully 'shrunk' by the outer div on the width, but NOT on the height. What I want is to have it shrunk on the height as well (so the inner div ajusts automatically if I change the height of the outer div)

Answer (score 0):

Will that do it for you? Don't know your limitations, though.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id='outer_div'>
      <div id='inner_div'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
   display: block;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   /* overflow: scroll; */
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: green;
}

#outer_div {
   display: table-row; 
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: purple;
}

#inner_div {
   display: table-cell; 
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

[View in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/46733/)

**Edit:** I don't know whether you can change the #inner_div or not, but if you do - then just simply remove `height` inside its rule...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. What I want to do is make a class called inner_div, that I could apply to div's of various heights. So I would choose a height of 2000px for the class, so that all div's that hav that class are ceiled by the parent div.

Comment: Must the `#outer_div` necessary be a `table-row`? If you say something like `#outer_div {
   display: block; 
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   overflow: scroll;
}` you're all set. Semantically wouldn't be really flawless but wrapping with a `display:block` sometimes helps out.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `max-height: value` to the inner div's CSS which corresponds to the height of your outer div so that the inner div's height will be "ceiled".